# Which CMS can I use for my project?

Tags: cms, video, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I have to build a new website for my client.. and he needs this stuff:

A user generated content website.. where users can upload their own videos.. (i will use a video hosting platform with api like fliqz.com)

I must manage a big user system.. where users can create their own "sub-users"... 
the site must manage paid subscriptions and payments through paypal.. and other payment gateways...

So the question is.. i have to use a pre-built CMS and extend it.. or just a good framework?

I've been thinking about joomla, drupal and expressionengine...

It's not neccesary to use a open source cms...

I've looking at drupal.. but is not as easy to understand and extend...

Can anyone help me to make a good decision?

Comment: Are you restricted by the server infrastructure? does it need to be LAMP or can it be Microsoft.NET based?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal would be the best choice if your after a pre-built CMS. ExpressionEngine isn't powerful enough to do what you want.

As far as frameworks go, I would go for Symfony. There is a learning curve but it's very very powerful.

Comment: we'll work on LAMP..
i've been looking at drupal.. and its a little hard to understand i think =(

i've worked a lot over CodeIgniter.. and the new EE version uses CI as base...

Answer (score 0):

Joomla is a popular CMS because it's easy to use and extensible, among other reasons. I suggest you check out [Windows Web App Gallery](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/categories.aspx?category=ContentMgmt). There is a large list of CMS's (for PHP and ASP.NET) that you can check out through there and also get ratings and reviews on them.

Also, you can download the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). This will give you a way to download any of the CMS's you find in the Windows Web App Gallery.

One last thing that would definitely make using the CMS's a lot easier for you would be to download [Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/).  This is a Microsoft development tool that makes it very easy to download and work with open source web applications.